# Getting facebook OAuthException after uninstalling facebook app once login from our application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting an exception when I click on the facebook button displayed in the image. The steps I am doing are listed below.

1) I am login in from my application when facebook is already installed on my mobile.

2) After that I uninstall the facebook application from my phone.

3) Now I start my application again and try to share the image but that shows the following error in toast.

[image]

Here is my code

```
mBinding.fragSocailmediaShareFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                CM.setSp(getActivity(), CV.SOCIALMEDIA_FB_ID, loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
                ShareOnFB();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
        if (CM.getSp(getActivity(), CV.SOCIALMEDIA_FB_ID, "").toString().length() > 0) {
            ShareOnFB();
        } else {
            mBinding.fragSocailmediaShareFb.performClick();
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled facebook extended permission ?

Comment: Which permission needs to be enabled? Can you please help me out?

Comment: Go through this blog post  https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/enable-extended-permissions-in-facebook-app/

Comment: they are asking me to upload the application. Should i have to upload the application to enable the permission?

Comment: I have uploaded the application of android and ios for app review but nothing happens. Can you tell me how much time it will take to review?